# python arguments changing in module

Tags: python, module

When I execute this code, the "list" argument is changed in the main module, but the the "i". Why? How can I change the "i" argument in the module ?

```
def func2(list, i):
    print (list, i)
    list += [4,1]
    i += 1
    print(list, i)
    return

j = 1
l = [0,1]
func2(l, j)
print("---",l , j)
```

Thanks to @JBernardo for the tip.
The real solution is to put the variable in a list. Now I can change both arguments and that is what I wanted.

```
def func2(list, i):
    print (list, i)
    list += [4,1]
    i[0] = i[0]+1
    print(list, i[0])
    return

j = [1]
l = [0,1]
func2(l, j) 
print("---",l , j[0])
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are mutable. You are changing their contents. A number is immutable, so you have to set it as `global` before to access outer scope

```
def func():
    global var1, var2
    var1 += [1,2,3]
    var2 = 5


var1 = [0, 1]
var2 = 7
func()
```

In this case the function receives no arguments since you want to change the global state

Comment: I would not link mutability to scope and namespaces necessarily. In fact, in your example you have removed both arguments from the signature of the function

Comment: @Pynchia Those are 2 different issues I addressed with the same solution, instead of doing one thing for each variable which would confuse a beginner

Comment: @JBernardo My understanding is that there is no way to keep the arguments and have j incremented ?